# PCL missing when building Indigo for raspberry pi

Tags: pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to setup the ros stack for indigo on my raspberry pi B+ according to

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

I deviate from the script and specified the robot and perception package and during the actual building of the workspace I get problems from the pcl_conversions package.  FindPCL.cmake seems to be missing causing tears.

This is what I get:

```
By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" with any of
the following names:

 PCLConfig.cmake
 pcl-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I'm quite new to ros so this is a major stumbling block for me.  I found some references that PCL needed to tweek some flags in the build scripts in src/pcl but there is no sorce code there for pcl.   Where should pcl be coming from? shouldn't the dependency resolve step figure out I need this one?

At a loss here, any help appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200731/pcl-missing-when-building-indigo-for-raspberry-pi/) by [Freyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21345/freyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran into the same issue, after installing the perception variant of ROS on a Raspberry PI 2.

Does anyone have or know of any good instructions on installing PCL on the RPI2 ?

I found this: http://rpi-hacks.blogspot.com/2013/08/pcl-compilation.html  however this is probably  for the first generation RPI, where cross compilation is way to circumvent the limited RAM issue. So I was wondering if anyone had already attempted to build PCL on the RPI2 - is there enough RAM on the RPI2 to compile PCL natively? Any other caveats?

Much appreciated

G

---

Originally posted by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) with karma: 73 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0